# Passing StateSpec.function as a val function

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I want to use mapwithsate function in sparkstreaming application..following the sample in [databrick website](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Streaming%20mapWithState.html)

```
def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, key: String, value: Option[Int], state: State[Long]): Option[(String, Long)] = {

val sum = value.getOrElse(0).toLong + state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
val output = (key, sum)
state.update(sum)
Some(output)
}


 val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(trackStateFunc _)
//.initialState(initialRDD)
.numPartitions(2)
.timeout(Seconds(batchIntervalSeconds*400))
```

The above code works perfectly..However, I want to define above function as val..since it would have less issue while I run the above code in cluster enwironment..

```
val trackStateFunc=(batchTime: Time, key: String, value: Option[Int], state: State[Long]) => {

val sum = value.getOrElse(0).toLong + state.getOption.getOrElse(0L)
val output = (key, sum)
state.update(sum)
Some(output)
}
val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(trackStateFunc _)
//.initialState(initialRDD)
 .numPartitions(2)
.timeout(Seconds(batchIntervalSeconds*400))
```

But I get compilation error while converting above to val (can not resove refrence with such a signature)

Comment: `def` defines a *method*, not a *function*, `methodName _` converts a *method* to a *function* (it's called eta-expansion), `val` in your second example defines a *function*, eta-conversion should not be applicable to functions, but still converts it to `() => oldFunction` (probably considers `val` as `def`), hence the error. In the first example you could have done `val f = trackStateFunc _; val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(f)`

Answer (score 1):

You have converted the method to a function but are still passing the function like a method with `trackStateFunc _`. Try this instead:

```
val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(trackStateFunc)
```